# SQL Column header contains the string DATE and it's creating an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    Convert(char(10), VAL_RPT_R230A.VAL_DATE, 121) As VAL_DATE, SEC_SCHEME_M020D.CLASS_4, VAL_RPT_R230A.QTY,VAL_RPT_R230A.SEC_REPORT_NAME1,SECURITY_M020A.TICKER,VAL_RPT_R230A.COST, VAL_RPT_R230A.MKT_VALUE,SECURITY_M020A.NATIONALITY, VAL_RPT_R230A.CLIENT_CODE, SEC_SCHEME_M020D.CLASS_2
FROM
    VAL_RPT_R230A VAL_RPT_R230A
INNER JOIN SECURITY_M020A SECURITY_M020A ON
        VAL_RPT_R230A.SEC_NO = SECURITY_M020A.SECURITY_NUMBER

LEFT OUTER JOIN SEC_SCHEME_M020D ON (VAL_RPT_R230A.SEC_NO=SEC_SCHEME_M020D.SECURITY_NUMBER)
WHERE
    VAL_RPT_R230A.QTY <> 0 AND VAL_RPT_R230A.USERID=dbo.SPM_GET_USERID_FN()  
AND VAL_RPT_R230A.JOB_CODE='ADHOC' AND VAL_RPT_R230A.INSTRUMENT <> 'CA' and VAL_RPT_R230A.EXTRACT_CODE='ADHOC' AND SEC_SCHEME_M020D.CLASS_DATE = 'GG'
```

Hi,

I'm doing a query on a table that contains a column header titled CLASS_DATE. However, the values under this column are strings and are not even dates. When I do my below query, I'm always getting an error because it's expecting a dates in the output. Can anyone help? The problem is coming from my last WHERE statement which is SEC_SCHEME_M020D.CLASS_DATE = 'GG'

Comment: What are the error message and database engine?

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error is : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: That suggests the datatype of `SEC_SCHEME_M020D.CLASS_DATE` is either `date` or `datetime`.  Why do you think this is not the case?

Comment: When I extract all the fields of the table SEC_SCHEME_M020D, the values under CLASS_DATE are ('BAL','GEN','GG','GGG','GI'). There's no dates or time, it's only STRINGS. The fact that there's the word 'DATE' in the column header is creating the error I assume? Since it's expecting to have dates/time as outputs but it's only strings.

Comment: What happens if you try this:  `select class_date from SEC_SCHEME_M020D where class_date = 'GG'`

Comment: I still get the same error message...

Comment: It sounds as though you have invalid values in your field.  The evidence leads to the Class_Date field is defined as a datetime type but you have string values somehow.  Double check your column definition in your database.  Please let us know if this is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to modify column definitions in the database. Is there a way to convert that column into strings in my query??